# HikariCP makes commit despite isAutoCommit = false

Tags: oracle, connection-pooling, spring-transactions, hikaricp

In integration tests, I want to add some synthetic data to every SQL in my application (because tables do not contain a predictable data). To reach it, I put some INSERT DML in *connectionInitSql* string of HikariConfig and set *isAutoCommit = false* to avoid polluting of my DB

```
    private fun getDataSource(name: String): DataSource {
      val poolConfig = dsconfig.getValue(name)
      val config = HikariConfig()
      config.jdbcUrl = poolConfig.jdbcUrl
      config.username = poolConfig.username
      config.password = poolConfig.password
      config.connectionTimeout = poolConfig.connectionTimeout
      config.maxLifetime = poolConfig.maxLifetime
      config.maximumPoolSize = poolConfig.maximumPoolSize
      config.isAutoCommit = false //!
      config.connectionInitSql = getConnectionInitSql()
      config.transactionIsolation = "TRANSACTION_SERIALIZABLE"
      return HikariDataSource(config)
   }

   private fun getConnectionInitSql(): String{
    var sqlStatementBuilder = StringBuilder()
    sqlStatementBuilder.append("begin\n")
    sqlStatementBuilder.append("execute immediate 'insert into hikari_test values (1)';\n")
    sqlStatementBuilder.append("end;")
    return sqlStatementBuilder.toString()
   }
```

I expect that my synthetic data will be exist in each Oracle session but won't be commited. But, when my unit-tests passed successfully, I see my synthetic data commited in DB. I recognized that commit take a place when HikariCP goes to shutdown:

```
2020-10-23T18:05:50.154+0300 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger] Gradle Test Executor 33 PASSED
2020-10-23T18:05:50.163+0300 [QUIET] [system.out] [] INFO    2020-10-23 18:05:50.166 [SpringContextShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource: HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2020-10-23T18:05:50.371+0300 [QUIET] [system.out] [] INFO    2020-10-23 18:05:50.383 [SpringContextShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource: HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2020-10-23T18:05:50.639+0300 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Changing state to: SUCCEEDED
2020-10-23T18:05:50.639+0300 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Process 'Gradle Test Executor 33' finished with exit value 0 (state: SUCCEEDED)
```

How can I totally avoid commit in the DB? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What about replacing

config.isAutoCommit = false //!

by

config.SetAutoCommit(false)

Comment: In Kotin, these are the same

Comment: Have you tried to set autocommit via spring.datasource.hikari.auto-commit

Comment: Yes. No effect.